# Как создать serializer, который передает одно значение в зависимости от условий?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть задача

необходимо отправить модальное окно пользователям приложения
1 - модалку показываем, закрыть нельзя
2 - модалку показываем, закрыть можно
3 - модалку НЕ показываем

Такую задачу не решал, поэтому не уверен, что правильно сформулирую вопрос, но попробую. Как и где мне необходимо прописать условие, чтобы передавались нужное значение (1, 2, 3)?

Все, что я знаю в моем коде ниже

```
class Tariff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Type(Enum):
        CANNOT_CLOSE = 1
        CAN_CLOSE = 2
        DONT_SHOW = 3


class TariffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tariff
        fields = ('sum', 'name')
```